# url redirect error to www or https

Tags: url, redirect, web, https, web-config

Sometimes my website redirects the visitors to my error page "is_error.aspx"
when some open the main page or any other pages, my website is ASP.NET and i use windows server 2012

the web.config contains this lines :

```
         <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/is_error.html">
              <error statusCode="404" redirect="/is_error.html" />
         </customErrors>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="index.aspx" />
      </files>
     </defaultDocument>
     <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath=""       path="/is_error.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/is_error.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/is_error.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/is_error.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
   <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.feee3\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.feee3.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="feee3Https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>      
    </system.webServer>
```

The "is_error.html" page :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>feee3.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="MM_goToURL('parent','is_error.aspx');return document.MM_returnValue">
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know is the problem from redirect my domain to "www"
or redirect it to "https" !
or could i write the "rewrite" section in web.config in another way? so in one line it redirect to "www" and "https" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time I found the problem, I just replace the lines in web.config :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/is_error.html">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="/is_error.html" />
</customErrors>
```

With this line :

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

I googled my website then click on the link, my website is opened
without errors, then i press backspace to back to previous page (my google search for my website) and click on my link again, i repeat this about 50 times
and at last the error appear, an image path is not found
The error is from my DataBase, there was image path stored in the DataBase but the image does not exist in the website folder, so i just delete the DataBase record, and every thing works perfect.